# $ajax call producing 'undefined' result

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I cannot get the data to show up in the page, though it appears in console.log.

Here is my query on api.php, the pages are in the same folder.

```
$Sub = $_GET['id'];
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT id, name FROM variables WHERE id=:id");
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $Sub, PDO::PARAM_STR);
try {$stmt->execute();} catch(PDOException $e){ echo errorHandle($e);}
$rs2 = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($rs2);
```

It is working fine and produces

```
{"id":"1","name":"James"} on api.php
```

Here is the .js and body

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js">
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p><div id="shoot">shoot</div>

<div id="output"></div>
   < script >
   $(document).ready(function() {
   $("#shoot").click(function() 
    {
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: 'api.php?id=1',          
      data: "?id=1",      
      dataType: 'json',      
      success: function(data)     
 {
       var id = data[0]; 
      var vname = data[1];
      $('#output').html("<b>id: </b>"+id+"<b> name: </b>"+vname); 
        console.log(data);
    } 
    });
  }); 
 });
  </script>         
        </body>
        </html>
```

I'm getting back

> id: undefined name: undefined

I've tried $ajax and any number of other changes but nothing is showing up in the page. 
Help would be appreciated

Comment: what does the rest of the HTML look like? and is the missing `<` in `script src` a bad paste?

Comment: I'll edit for completeness.

Comment: `url: 'api.php?id=1', data: "?id=1"` => `url: 'api.php', data: {id : 1}` when using `$.ajax`. (The data can be formatted in multiple ways, you could also use `data: "id=1"`)

Comment: I'll give that a shot. Hold on.

Comment: @Qirel Okay, I tried: 
    $.ajax({  type: "GET",  url: 'api.php',     data: {id : 1}, 
but got the same undefined.

Comment: What is the respons of `console.log(data);`?

Comment: Object {id: "1", name: "James"}

Comment: That's got it Qirel. Thank you very much. If you'll put this as an answer, I'll upvote you when the system lets me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things to note

1. You're statically setting the ID when you set the URL-parameter, yet passing it as an argument in `data` as well. You should reference the file in the `url` parameter, and pass all relevant values in the `data` parameter.
2. The data-parameter has an invalid `?` in front.
3. Actual issue: You get an associative JSON object returned, not an array, so you'll need to access it as such, with `data.id` instead of `data[0]`.

The AJAX-call should look something like this.

```
$.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: 'api.php',          
      data: {id:1},      
      dataType: 'json',      
      success: function(data) {
          var id = data.id; 
          var vname = data.name;
          $('#output').html("<b>id: </b>"+id+"<b> name: </b>"+vname); 
          console.log(data);
     } 
});
```

This assumes that you have set the PHP header to return it as JSON, with

```
header("Content-Type: application/json");
```

when you use `echo json_encode(..)`.

---

The values passed in the `data` parameter can be formatted in several ways, I've chosen a `{id:1}` in this example, but `"id=1"` would be valid as well.

Comment: That is an even cleaner answer. I'll work with making the id dynamic in a bit but I can probably handle that. It was the parseJSON(data) or the data.id that I couldn't find anywhere in the tuts I read.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: There is no need to use $.parseJSON when you are returning data with PHP's json_encode. Just access the data with data.id and data.vname. Also, as of jQuery 3.0, $.parseJSON is deprecated.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Qirel wrote it for me both ways, so now I have a choice in the future. Stack rocks! Thanks for your help and confirmation, Ravi.

Comment: As Ravi stated, its already an object (set by the PHP header I assume, I originally thought it was a string returned) - so you can access it directly, but as an object - not an array. I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

On your $.ajax call do not pass the data: "?id=1". By doing that, you are hard-coding the response. So remove that line. That should fix the response coming back to AJAX.

Also, on success: function(data), the data you get back needs to be accessed in this manner:

data.id and data.vname.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Ravi. That was one of the options I had altered along the way with no results. But @Qirel spotted the problem for me.